# Swagger UI: how to hide Nest.js controller method argument input field?

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I'm adding Swagger UI 4 to existing Nest.js 7 project.

There was `@Headers` decorator for the Nest.js controller method argument.

I added `@ApiBearerAuth` nest.js decorator for method.

```
    @ApiBearerAuth('MyAuth')
    @Get()
    async getEmployees(
        @Headers('Authorization')
        auth: string,

        @Query() query: EmployeesQuery,
    ) {
```

The result is that I have Authorization header input field and lock icon button in Swagger UI at the same time. Lock icon button authorization works. Authorization header input field doesn't work and  Swagger UI requires to fill it (input value is actually ignored by Nest.js).

How can I make Swagger authorization field to become not required and hidden?

[image: Swagger UI screenshot]

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Found how to make not required:

```
    @ApiBearerAuth('MyAuth')
    @ApiParam({
        name: 'Authorization',
        required: false,
        description:
            '(Leave empty. Use lock icon on the top-right to authorize)',
    })
    @Get()
    async getEmployees(
        @Headers('Authorization') auth: string,
        @Query() query: EmployeesQuery,
    ) {
```

[image: Screenshots]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative could be to use **@Req()** instead of **@Headers()**.

```
@Get()
async getEmployees(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Query() query: EmployeesQuery,
  ): Promise<Employees[]> {
  const token = req.headers.authorization;
  .
  .
  .
```

Note: import the type **Request** from **express**.

```
import { Request } from 'express';
```

Comment: Thank you @jagannath-gouda . This was the only way to omit this header

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a custom decorator.
It's better than the first answer because you don't have to pass the entire request for testing and actually hide the header in opposite to the second answer.

```
const AuthorizationToken = createParamDecorator(
  (data: string, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.headers.authorization;
  },
);
```